# Display resources for each factory in the Rocket Valley Tycoon

Tags: python, beginner

I'm new here. I'm trying to teach myself programming by learning Python. I have assigned myself the following task.

There's a game I'm playing (Rocket Valley Tycoon) where the goal is to basically place an Extractor to gather resources, then use Factories to transform the resource into a good, which then usually gets processed again by another Factory into a processed good.

The point of the program I'm trying to write is to be able to see the resources needed for any Factory. So, for example, Copper plates need 10 carbon and 20 copper ore, and at the same time, the carbon needs 2 coal and 4 water, so I would like the final output to be something like:

Copper plates need 20 copper ore, 20 coal, and 40 water. I have a working prototype, that works with just this, but if I know it can be simplified somehow. (Especially in the print_total function)

Also, this only works with a Factory that has just one "child" Factory and not with n "child" Factories. This is the first tech tree: [image: You can see the first tech tree here:]

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
class Factory:

    def __init__(self, name, ing1, amount1, ing2=None, amount2=None):
        self.name = name
        self.ing1 = ing1
        self.amount1 = amount1
        self.ing2 = ing2
        self.amount2 = amount2
        self.total_amount1_1 = None
        self.total_amount1_2 = None
        self.total_amount2_1 = None
        self.total_amount2_2 = None
        self.total_ing1_ing1 = None
        self.total_ing1_ing2 = None
        self.total_ing2_ing1 = None
        self.total_ing2_ing2 = None

    def print_ing(self):
        print(self.name + ' needs: ')
        print(self.amount1, self.ing1.name, self.amount2, self.ing2.name)

    def print_total(self):
        if isinstance(self.ing1, Factory):
            print('Ing1 is Factory')
            self.total_ing1_ing1 = self.ing1.ing1
            self.total_ing1_ing2 = self.ing1.ing2
            self.total_amount1_1 = self.amount1 * self.ing1.amount1
            self.total_amount1_2 = self.amount1 * self.ing1.amount2
        elif isinstance(self.ing2, Factory):
            print('Ing2 is Factory')
            self.total_ing2_ing1 = self.ing2.ing1
            self.total_ing2_ing2 = self.ing2.ing2
            self.total_amount2_1 = self.amount2 * self.ing2.amount1
            self.total_amount2_2 = self.amount2 * self.ing2.amount2
        print(self.name + ' needs: ')
        print(self.amount1, self.ing1.name, self.total_amount2_1, 
              self.total_ing2_ing1.name, self.total_amount2_2,\
              self.total_ing2_ing2.name)


class Extractor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


coal = Extractor('Coal')
water = Extractor('Water')
copper_ore = Extractor('Copper Ore')
carbon = Factory('Carbon', coal, 2, water, 4)
copper_plates = Factory('Copper Plates', copper_ore, 20, carbon, 10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would turn this into one class that takes a list of ingredients and cost tuples. The resulting object can be added with another of its instance or multiplied with a number.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Ingredient:

    def __init__(self, *ingredients):
        self.d = defaultdict(int)
        if len(ingredients) == 1 and isinstance(ingredients[0], str):
            # special case for base ingredients
            self.d[ingredients[0]] = 1
        else:
            for ingredient, amount in ingredients:
                self.d[ingredient] += amount

    @property
    def ingredients(self):
        return list(self.d.keys())

    @property
    def amounts(self):
        return list(self.d.values())

    def __rmul__(self, other):
         # allows doing other * self, where other is a number
        return Ingredient(*zip(self.ingredients, [other * x for x in self.amounts]))

    def __add__(self, other):
        # allows self + other, where other is another Ingredient
        return Ingredient(*zip(self.ingredients + other.ingredients,
                               self.amounts + other.amounts))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(self.d.items()))
```

Then you can define the base items and any derived item is just algebraic manipulations:

```
coal = Ingredient("Coal")
water = Ingredient("Water")
copper_ore = Ingredient("Copper Ore")
carbon = 2 * water + 4 * coal
copper_plates = 20 * copper_ore + 10 * carbon
print(copper_plates)
# [('Copper Ore', 20), ('Water', 20), ('Coal', 40)]
```

Comment: This works exactly like I intended to without being too complicated, thanks! I was looking at things like weighted directed graphs and found it too hard to grasp for now. Thanks!

Comment: Took me quite a while to read and understand everything, and with a bit of work, I understood everything now, except that, I don't get why len(ingredients[0]) != 2, can you explain that, please?

Comment: @OliverAragon When doing e.g. `10 * coal`, the constructor of the class gets called like this: `Ingredient((coal, 10))`. Note that the first and only argument is a tuple of length two. There is only one ingredient, but it comes with an amount. This needs to be distinguished from `Ingredient("Coal")`, which is why I added the second `len` check. In the first case `ingredients == [(coal, 10)]`, in the second case it is just `ingredients == ["Coal"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- It looks like the `Extractor` and amount belong together in some object, perhaps `Ingredient`. This would make it easier to see the connection between your now paired `Factory` constructor arguments, and would make it easy to pass an arbitrary number of `Extractor`s - just make it a list argument.
- `Extractor`s are effectively enums, and [Python 3 supports these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).
- Some of your attributes are never really used. `total_amount1_1` is assigned to, but never read.
- Attributes which are only used in one method (such as `total_ing1_ing1`) should be local variables instead.
- Calculating and printing the results of the calculation should not be intermingled.
- [`isinstance` should be avoided in a duck typed language like Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549018/whats-the-python-version-for-code-against-an-interface-not-an-object).
- A `main` method which takes what you want to convert from and to would make the code reusable elsewhere. Have a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for more.
- I would encourage writing some tests of your conversions to make sure the changes don't break anything, and to check out TDD - this sort of simple problem is a perfect way to learn TDD from scratch.

Once you have these done it should hopefully be easier to see how you could have recursive factories.

Comment: I'm not sold on "`isinstance` should be avoided in a duck typed language like Python". Maybe you could say why you shouldn't use it in this case?

Comment: @Peilonrayz I linked to a thorough and relevant discussion, and there's lots of articles explaining this better than I could do. As far as I can tell it's basically community consensus by now.

Comment: Yes, I read your link, and don't find it to be very relevant. Most of your answer is just 'don't do this' or 'do this', but doesn't say why you should or shouldn't. Yes there are links online, but what's the point in posting a review if you're not willing to explain the 'why'?